# How do sharp objects deflect radio waves?

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics

This technology is used in stealth aircraft.The pointed nose of aircraft deflect those incident waves but not reflect back.Also speculate in case of rounded object with those waves.[image]

Comment: This is just the ordinary law of specular reflection. Angle of reflection equals angle of incidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat metal surfaces reflect radio waves the same way that mirrors reflect light beams. for the case of a flat metal surface on a plane being hit with a radar beam from an antenna on the ground a distance away, almost none of the incident beam bounces off backwards in the direction of the receiving antenna and so a plane built of such flat surfaces yields a very small signal return and becomes hard to see on radar.

For a curved surface facing an incoming radar beam,  a significant fraction of the energy of the incoming beam bounces off the curve and heads back towards the antenna. Airplanes with curved surfaces are therefore easier to see with radar.